# How to arrange pie charts randomly in a named range?

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I have a code which draws pie chart based on some criteria and the charts are positioned based on the criteria. In case of multiple items with same inputs charts overlap. Something like this.

[image]

Here is the code that positions the charts.

```
Set Rng = Range("BT_GATE1")

    Debug.Print Rng.Address
    Debug.Print Rng.Top
    Debug.Print Rng.Parent.Name
    Set ChtObj = ActiveChart.Parent
    ChtObj.Top = Rng.Top
    ChtObj.Left = Rng.Left
```

Can we place the charts randomly in the named range so that they are visible separately? Something like this.

[image]

Comment: You could use `WorksheetFunction.RandBetween` to pick a random row/column number in that range, in effect finding a random cell within it.

Comment: Hi BigBen can you please elaborate on the syntax? Can I use named ranges within that function?  Do you mean I select random cell by worksheet function and move my chart top and left to that cell?

Comment: Let's say your named range `Range("BT_GATE1")` has 4 columns and 10 rows (you can get those values with `Range("BT_GATE1").Columns.Count` and `Range("BT_GATE1").Rows.Count`. Then use those values within `RandBetween` - so to get a random row number, `RandBetween(1, 10)`, and similarly for the column. With that random row/column number, you can then select a random cell within the named range: `Range("BT_GATE1").Cells(randomRow, randomColumn)`.

Comment: Actually, even better, you can just use `RandBetween` once - you don't need a random row and column number, you just need a random cell number.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a helper function like this can easily return a random cell within the named range:

```
Public Function GetRandomCellWithin(ByVal rng As Range) As Range
    With rng
        Dim randomCellNumber As Long
        randomCellNumber = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, .Cells.Count)
        
        Set GetRandomCellWithin = .Cells(randomCellNumber)
    End With
End Function
```

You can then use the `.Top` and `.Left` of the random cell to reposition your charts randomly within the main named range.

Comment: Thanks BigBen. I will check this function, but as I am beginner I found earlier solution of counting rows in range and getting first row and last row. That helps me see whats happening. But will definitely check the function.